# Can you play Yoda in Star Wars Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I heard there is a way to choose Yoda as character in the game *Star wars battlefront*.

Is it true? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been rumors of Yoda becoming a character in the game for over a year, but he has not been released or officially announced.

So no, you can't choose Yoda in the game as of right now. This may change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the first Star wars battlefront you could not play as Yoda. But since then Star wars battlefront II has come out and Yoda is a option to play as. So unless you have the new game then no you cannot play as Yoda.

Comment: This answer seems to regard the 2004 and 2005 games, but the question specifies the 2015 game.

Comment: this answer does not regard the 2004 and 2005 games.  In Battlefront 2 **2017** you can play as yoda.